# How to prevent double values from getting truncated?

Tags: c++

---

This is a reproducible C++ program:

```
#include <RInside.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RInside R (argc, argv);
    SEXP ans = R.parseEval ("m <- 40.702147");

    Rcpp::NumericVector v (ans);           

    for (int i=0; i< v.size(); i++) 
    {           
        std::cout << "In C++ element " << i << " is " << v[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Makefile's here:

```
## -*- mode: make; tab-width: 8; -*-
##
## Simple Makefile
##
## TODO: 
##  proper configure for non-Debian file locations,   [ Done ]
##  allow RHOME to be set for non-default R etc

## comment this out if you need a different version of R, 
## and set set R_HOME accordingly as an environment variable
R_HOME :=       $(shell R RHOME)

sources :=      $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs :=         $(sources:.cpp=)


## include headers and libraries for R 
RCPPFLAGS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --cppflags)
RLDFLAGS :=         $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
RBLAS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config BLAS_LIBS)
RLAPACK :=      $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)

## if you need to set an rpath to R itself, also uncomment
#RRPATH :=      -Wl,-rpath,$(R_HOME)/lib

## include headers and libraries for Rcpp interface classes
RCPPINCL :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RCPPLIBS :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)


## include headers and libraries for RInside embedding classes
RINSIDEINCL :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RINSIDELIBS :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)

## compiler etc settings used in default make rules
CXX :=          $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX)
CPPFLAGS :=         -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS :=         $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS :=       $(RLDFLAGS) $(RRPATH) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RCPPLIBS) $(RINSIDELIBS)

all:            $(programs)
            @test -x /usr/bin/strip && strip $^

run:            $(programs)
            @for p in $(programs); do echo; echo "Running $$p:"; ./$$p; done

clean:
            rm -vf $(programs)
            rm -vrf *.dSYM

runAll:
            for p in $(programs); do echo "Running $$p"; ./$$p; done
```

---

Output of this program:

```
In C++ element 0 is 40.7021
```

---

**The problem is that the value `40.702147` is getting "truncated" to `40.7021`.**
I want it full.
What is the way out?

Comment: That's why I prefer C's `printf()`.

Comment: Maybe it's getting "truncated", but it's definitely not truncated! :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB The spelling are still same, you hinted the double quotes?

Comment: @H2CO3: because `%9.21f` is somehow better than the C++ type-aware `setXXX` I/O manipulators? If you're going to code C++, code it. Don't be in some hybrid state. As Yoda would say: "No. Try not. Do. Or do not" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I don't want to mix C++ and C, I know that's terrible practice. I think I should have said "That's why I prefer C" to satisfy you, but that sounds like it has no relation to this very problem...

Comment: Only try to realize the truth: Then you'll see that it is not the *value* that is truncated, but only your *output*.

Comment: Reproducible is good. Minimally reproducible is better. A bit of effort could have produced a two-line C++ program that showed the same problem, then you wouldn't need all the unnecessary code and tags, and you would have focussed the problem to C++ programmers rather than dragging in the R users!

Comment: @H2CO3, I stand corrected. Apologies.

Comment: @paxdiablo no need to apologize, I wasn't angry of you. :)

Comment: @Spacedman If I knew the cout was at fault I wouldn't have tag R here. And what do you mean by "dragging in the R users"? Did I send them personal mails/spams? All I did was to make an effort to create a better question as compared to my previous ones!

Comment: But tagging it R when the problem was nothing to do with R meant the question came up on our 'dashboards'. And we looked at it. And the problem wasn't anything to do with R. And we sighed... :)

Comment: @Spacedman I was under an impression that it is R which is not giving the full double values. I couldn't have known better without asking it! I spent hours on google trying to find another function in R which could handle the double values. Thankfully at last I decided to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value itself is not being truncated <sup>(a)</sup>, the `cout` output stream is using the defaults for output.

You can look into the `iomanip` header to find ways to force a specific output format, such as:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision (9) << v[i] << '\n';
```

This complete program here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main (void) {
    double d = 40.702147;
    std::cout << d << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setprecision (9) << d << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
40.7021
40.702147
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: Keep in mind it *may* be truncated if it cannot be represented exactly as an IEEE754 double precision value but that's not the case here - doubles have about fifteen decimal digits of precision and you're only seeing six.

Comment: I am "very" glad. I was very worried that the NumericVector from R is producing truncated values. I had spent a good amount of time in figuring out a better function in R. :damn:

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the `std::cout` precision by:

```
std::cout.precision(16);
```

or use

```
std::cout << std::setprecision (9) << val;
```

as paxdiablo and Joachim suggested

Comment: Or use the I/O manipulator [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) inline in the stream.